# compareGroups package - how to specify destination path in R when exporting files?

Tags: r, export

Beginner to R! Bit of a bizarre question, but is anyone familiar with the compareGroups package in R? There's a function to export files, but I have no idea where the file ends up in - can't seem to find it doing a computer search. (I use RStudio). The CRAN guide wasn't particularly helpful.

The functions I tried were export2csv() and export2word()

Thank you!

Comment: It should go to your working directory. Try running `getwd()`.

Comment: Unfortunately no, it's quite bizarre. I tried following the package guide step-by-step. Perhaps it's my RStudio setting?

Answer (score 0):

If you run

```
getwd()
```

you should get back the directory path that RStudio is using for your current project at that moment. If you do not specify a special destination for the export, I believe it should output it in that directory. You can also run

```
list.files()
```

to list the files in your current working project directory

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Problem turned out to be formula, even though I didn't get an error prompt. I reverted to the package's old formula for exporting somewhere on the web and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Oddly the formula doesn't follow instructions in the package's manual. In case anyone else gets the same problem, `export2word(createTable(compareGroups(x ~ y1 + y2, data=dataset), file="filename.doc")`